# How to make an ipad app impossible to close

Tags: xcode, uibutton, plist, exit

I am programming an app for an experiment by the University of Queensland Psych Department.  The app needs to be impossible to exit, or at least it would be preferable if it were impossible to exit.  This is not a virus- it is for an experiment with the Grute Eylandt Aborigines. Anyways, do any of you guys have any idea how to set the app to be impossible to exit, or even better, to set it so that you have to enter a password to exit it?  Furthermore, on a separate subject, do you guys have any idea how I can save the information in the app to the iPhone?  This app will not go through the App Store so it does not need to follow App Store rules.  Therefore, if there was a way to save "Button (whatever button it is) pushed at (time and date)" to the notes section of the iPhone every time a button was pushed in the app, and/or to save audio recorded using the AudioToolbox framework to the actual iPod library, that would be fantastic.  Otherwise I would have to make some sort of db or plist file to save everything with if-then statements, I think.  Thank you!

Comment: You'd probably need to jail break it ... :/

Comment: Even jail-breaking won't stop somebody from pressing the home button or powering off the device.  Using a case or enclosure designed for kiosk use (we do this for some applications at the hospital I work for) prevents physical access the the home button or the power button.

Comment: There are apps who let you change the behavior of the gestures and the home button (only when jailbroken). You should split this question. One question for the close issue, other for the database issue. This way you will get better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check-out iOS 6 [Accessibility](http://www.apple.com/ios/ios6/#accessibility) feature:

> It allows a parent, teacher, or administrator to limit an iOS device
>   to one app by disabling the Home button, as well as restrict touch
>   input on certain areas of the screen

Comment: 4+ years later, I found this question of mine while writing a meta-SO post about question style, and your answer is clearly the correct one.  Sorry it took me so long!

Answer (score 0):

Put the device in a "kiosk" case so keep the home button from being pressed. For storing the data to the device, if it is a small amount of data, use `NSUserDefaults`, if this will be a large amount of data, I would lean more toward `Core Data`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution on the market -- MOKIMOBILITY has developed software that allows you to lock the home button.  It is Mobile Device Management software with a full range of security features.  It essentially locks down your iPad so the user is only able to use what you what them to use.  It is called +MDM  www.mokimobility.com  The software can be managed mobile-y from a central interface.  Slick software.